# Append() doesn't work on JTextArea element

Tags: java, swing, append, jtextarea

I want to create graphic console which will give user information about current state of program. I've planned to use for it JTextArea, but I have a problem with append() method. Even after using it in main class I still have empty JTextArea. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code of gui of console:

```
package com.meh;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Controller extends JFrame {
    public JPanel ControlPanel;
    public JTextArea Log;

    static void setView() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Controller");
        frame.setContentPane(new Controller().ControlPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And this is the code of main class:

```
package com.meh;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Controller controller = new Controller();
        controller.setView();
        controller.Log.append("Hello");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look up the `jTextArea` append method, you will see that:

```
Appends the given text to the end of the document
```

However, it doesn't do anything if the `String` is empty or `null`.

You could use `setText()` in your case.

Comment: Hmmm... I've changed append() to setText(), but I still have the same problem.

Comment: I'm on my phone but it looks like you may not have added the text area to the jframe

Comment: Or possibly initialise the jTextArea

Comment: Log = new jTextArea(); frame.add(Log);

Answer (score 1):

If you call `getText()` is the new string value returned? If so, you might need to call [repaint()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint()) and/or [revalidate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate()) on `controller` and/or `controller.Log` after changing the text.

Answer (score 1):

As I see, you never initialize 'ControlPanel', it will always be null so you can't do anything to it.